# How to select a row according to sum of values from another column?

Tags: mysql, sum

I have a table called `stock` which is designed like this:

```
| ID | product_id | qty |
|----|------------|-----|
|   1|       1    |  4  |
|   2|       1    |  3  |
|   3|       2    |  10 |
|   4|       2    |  15 | 
|   5|       3    |  2  |
```

From this table I want to select the `product_id` where total quantity less than 10.
According to this table selection (product_id) must be

- 1
- 3

Here is what I have tried so far:

```
SELECT product_id 
FROM stock 
WHERE 10>(SELECT SUM(quantity) FROM stock)
```

Please help me figure out why this won't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This won't work because if you are using an aggregate function you have to put it in the HAVING clause. You also want to group by the product_id so the SUM() function knows which groups to sum.

Try this:

```
SELECT product_id
FROM stock
GROUP BY product_id
HAVING SUM(quantity) < 10;
```

Here is the [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/12e358/3) example for you.

Answer (score -1):

```
SELECT product_id, SUM(qty) tot_stock 
FROM stock
GROUP BY 1
HAVING tot_stock < 10
```

This gives you the total stock as well, which you can discard if you don't need.

But, if you want to send *only* the product ids to the client, wrap the above query into another select like this:

```
SELECT product_id FROM (SELECT product_id, SUM(qty) tot_stock 
FROM stock
GROUP BY 1
HAVING tot_stock < 10) a
```